# Create Slider to start/stop/move Point

Tags: graphics, dynamic

I want to be able to start, stop, and move the dynamically moving point simultaneously in both animations. The "PlayPauseButton" in the animations only controls the given animation. Indeed, I want both animations to always by synchronized.

```
system = {x'[t] == 2 x[t] - 0.08 x[t] y[t], x[0] == 400,
          y'[t] == -y[t] + 0.01 x[t] y[t], y[0] == 25};
sol = NDSolve[system, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 21.5}];
{x1[t_], y1[t_]} = {x[t], y[t]} /. Flatten[sol];

px4 = Plot[x1[t], {t, 0, 21.5}, PlotRange -> {0, 400}, PlotStyle -> {Black}];
py4 = Plot[y1[t], {t, 0, 21.5}, PlotRange -> {0, 400}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed}];

Row[
 {Animate[
   Show[px4, py4,
    Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[Dynamic[{t, x1[t]}]], 
              Point[Dynamic[{t, y1[t]}]]}]], {t, 0, 21.5, 
   AppearanceElements -> "PlayPauseButton"}, SaveDefinitions -> True,
   AnimationRate -> 0.251, AppearanceElements -> "PlayPauseButton", 
   BaselinePosition -> Bottom],
  Animate[
   Show[ParametricPlot[{x1[t], y1[t]},{t, 0, 5.375}, AxesLabel -> {"Prey", "Predator"}, 
                        AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, 80}}], 
        Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x1[t], y1[t]}]}]],
   {t, 0, 5.375, AppearanceElements -> "PlayPauseButton"}, 
   SaveDefinitions -> True, AnimationRate -> 0.251, 
   BaselinePosition -> Bottom]}, Frame -> True, RoundingRadius -> 10]
```

The desired slider should fit into the frame space above the first "Animate". Perhaps I could have rewritten this code with Manipulate, but I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: Stephen, thanks for the accept - you might also wait some time and see if other answers drop in (Qs with accepted answers tend to draw less new answers) and then decide to accept mine ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slight rewrite of your code using `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{Show[px4, py4, 
    Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[Dynamic[{t, x1[t]}]], 
      Point[Dynamic[{t, y1[t]}]]}]], 
   Show[ParametricPlot[{x1[t], y1[t]}, {t, 0, 5.375}, 
     AxesLabel -> {"Prey", "Predator"}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, 80}}], 
    Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x1[t], y1[t]}]}]]}, 
  Frame -> True], {t, 0, 21.5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You have different domains for your two `Animate`s, but it somehow seems to work out in a cyclical fashion in this case.

As noted by @MichaelE2, a closer fit to the original `Animate` can be achieved in this way (layout changed to accomodate larger control bar):

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{Show[px4, py4, 
     Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[Dynamic[{t, x1[t]}]], 
       Point[Dynamic[{t, y1[t]}]]}]], 
    Show[ParametricPlot[{x1[t], y1[t]}, {t, 0, 5.375}, 
      AxesLabel -> {"Prey", "Predator"}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, 80}}], 
     Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x1[t], y1[t]}]}]]}}, 
  Frame -> True], {t, 0, 21.5}, ControlType -> Animator]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Control type `Animator` for `t` might be more in line with the OP's wishes.

Comment: @MichaelE2 feel free to modifiy - I just took the quickest route :-)

Comment: I'll just leave it as comment.  One can always click the + and use the animator that comes with the slider.  I really just meant to point out another possibility.

Comment: @MichaelE2 added - thanks for the tip (in fact I never used that `Control` type specifically).

Comment: The domain for the first animate reflects just 4 periods. Had I used the same domain for the second animate, errors from NDSolve creep in which are reflected in the orbit. Thus I used just one period for the second animate and cut its animation rate by 1/4. Thanks both of you for your help

Comment: @Stephen o.k. - you could of course use some fraction of `t` as argument inside the manipulate as well (again, I was just lazy/sloppy).